# Wrong MAC Address on android 10

Tags: java, android, mac-address, android-10.0, wifi-direct

**Requirement** :

Need to fetch correct MacAddress from android Device .

I am using below code for fetching MacAddress .

**Code** :

```
private static String getMacAddress() {
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();

            if (TextUtils.equals(networkInterface.getName(), "wlon0")) {
                byte[] bytes = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : bytes) {
                    builder.append(String.format("%02X:", b));
                }

                if (builder.length() > 0) {
                    builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
                }

                return builder.toString();
            }
        }

        return "";
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Get Mac Address Error", e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Problem** :

i have tried above code to fetch macAddress , but i am getting wrong address on   android 10 but on other versions below 10 , i am able to get correct address . i have also tried replacing wlon0 with p2p0, but it didn't work .

**FYI** :

I am not connected to internet but my wifi is on , Because i am using WifiDirect for P2P Communication .

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: MAC addresses are randomized since Android 10 and there is not much we can do. If you are trying to use it as an ID it's not viable anymore

Comment: Hi @javdromero

Thanks for your comment .

what if want to use macAddress without internet but my wifi will be active(wifiDirect case) .

also , i can see 3 different macAddresses when wifi state changed .

Comment: [It's gonna be random](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization?hl=en). "MAC randomization is enabled by default for client mode, SoftAp, and Wi-Fi Direct."

Comment: @javdromero 

ok got it .

one more question :

Is there anything that i can use in place of macAddress that is specific to a particular android device and it can be fetched programatically ?

Comment: [Android recomendations](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) , I use [fingerprintjs](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprint-android) library kepp in mind this is not an official or recognized library by google, it's an alternative

Comment: @javdromero. Thanks